# Can Python Create 2D Games?

Tags: python

Is it possible to make 2D games using python? If it is got any links to any 2D game that used Python to create it? I was thinking of learning Python but thought i should ask you guys if it can create 2D games before I do start.

Comment: of coarse its possible .... see pygame library ... or pyglet or ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best toolkit for doing 2d game programming with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611/whats-the-best-toolkit-for-doing-2d-game-programming-with-python)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, check out [http://pygame.org](http://pygame.org/news.html)

It's a pretty popular 2D library for Python.

Answer (score 2):

I use [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) myself and it is very good. It has good documentation and tutorials, and is quite well designed. I've also heard wonderful reviews of [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/).

[Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34611/2502012)